# Why is the applied image texture not stretched to the seam?

Tags: uv

I am yet to wrap my head around uv maps and unwrapping but what exactly should I do to make sure that the texture shows up all the way to the seam. I want the bottom part of the label image to align with the seam I've marked. As you can see the faces in the uv editor have texture showing all the way down to the bottom of the face, but on the can, the picture does stretch up to the seam and is filled with some black band at the bottom instead of the orange texture all the way to the seam. How do I go about doing that?
Thank you for you time people.[image]

Comment: Rotate the UV map 90 and then shape it to match the image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Maulik. I tried the suggestion but did not work for me. I am still unable to get the texture to line up. Here is the link to the file if you are interested and have some time to tinker. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1prYVm7YtQIjT5UXrMyeS3uh6veRXmIMH/view?usp=sharing